# Typescript 3.5 loop HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLImageElement> not completed

Tags: typescript, loops, htmlcollection

This is my function :

```
let tableData: any = document.getElementById('serversTable');

let images: any = tableData.getElementsByTagName('img');
console.log(images.length); // displays 5 in console 

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   var os = images[i].alt;

   var sp1 = document.createElement("span");
   sp1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(os));
   images[i].parentNode.replaceChild(sp1, images[i]);
}
```

The line `console.log(i);` displays `0`, `1`, and `2`. 
`3` and `4` are not displayed in the console, while `images.length` equals 5.

So the loop isn't completed, i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it :

```
 let serverTableData: any = document.getElementById('serversTable');

 let images2: any = serverTableData.getElementsByTagName('img');
 let images: any = Array.from(images2);
 for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   var os = images[i].alt;
   var sp1 = document.createElement("span");
   sp1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(os));
   images[i].parentNode.replaceChild(sp1, images[i]);
 }
```